# How to view the total number of Posts and the top 100 users with the highest points in the MMA section of stackexchange

Tags: discussion

Since I am a new user of stackexchange learning community, I want to find the top 100 users with the highest points (Community Ranking) in the MMA section of stackexchange to learn their published articles, but I can't find the relevant settings or links.

Comment: This belongs to meta, but in any case there’s a [“Users” link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users) in the list on the left of each page, towards the top. On that page you can select user rankings by “Reputation”, then “All” as time filter. The total number of questions is shown towards the top of the list if you select the [“Questions”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions) link from the same list.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

Comment: [rank is here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/387/alltime/mathematica/2012-01-17/121#121)